# RuntimeException in Android

Tags: android

These are all the "red lines" in my LogCat

```
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start activity ComponentInfo{com.balance.start/com.balance.start.MainView}:       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:408)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:482)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:477)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at com.balance.start.MainView.onCreate(MainView.java:62)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
01-10 17:56:34.294: E/AndroidRuntime(16243):    ... 11 more
```

I've specified

```
uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

and my phone has android 2.2.1 version.

Why is it not working? 
Now please help.

Comment: please add your detailed crashlog.

Comment: hey check your app build sdk

Comment: It works fine on virtual devices(AVD). So, is there any possibility that something is wrong with the SDK?

Comment: LogCat shows this..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end

Comment: @ShivamMangla : You need to show your code first. Then tell what your code does and finally where is the problem.

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673888/illegal-argument-exception-in-android-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be some layout issue.Have mainted all attributes of your layout properly

Comment: Actually I'm unable to locate the error. So, I don't know which code should I post. I've specified the code that I've used in my manifest. But I don't know what else to post. :/
Help me here which code should I post ?

Comment: @ShivamMangla : can you see red lines in logcat. just copy all those lines, click on edit in your qestion and post it there.

Comment: at com.balance.start.MainView.onCreate(MainView.java:62) In your MainView.java class at line 62 in oncreate you got some exeption.so post that code here

Comment: dp.init(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, null);
dp is my datepicker element..

Comment: Ya.. I commented that line out & it worked. Thanks a lot. Actually I don't really know too much about the LogCat.
I can just copy paste the errors from it.
Anyways.. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Once use final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();dp.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);